# Passing multiple system properties to spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, system-properties

I am trying to run a Spark job using spark-submit in Windows. I am executing the below spark-submit command from command prompt.

> spark-submit **--driver-class-path** %FILE_NAME%\config 
>   **--files** %FILE_NAME%\config\app.conf,%FILE_NAME%\config\log4j.properties **--conf**
>   "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcassandra.username=cassandra
>   -Dcassandra.password=cassandra@123" **--class** com.sapient.main.MainApp %FILE_NAME%\lib\test.jar

Here, I am trying to pass two system properties using `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` one is `cassandra.username` and other is `cassandra.password` but on executing the command, I am getting below error

```
The input line is too long.
```

However, if I pass only one system property to `extraJavaOptions` and without double quotes `""` like below, then everything works fine.

```
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcassandra.username=cassandra
```

But I need to pass 2 system properties. How can I resolve this? Also let me know if there is another way to pass system properties to spark which could avoid this issue.

**Note:** It runs in linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conf file and pass it to spark-submit

or

pass it like below

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcassandra.username=cassandra\
--conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024\
--conf spark.network,timeout=1000\
```

Comment: need to provide multiple system properties i.e. multiple key-value pairs in extraJavaOptions.. how to do that?

Comment: can you try something like                                                                                                                                 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcassandra.configuration=file:/data/security.properties